# AWS CustomTabsManagerActivity.java crash on android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito for authentication in my application and I am getting a strange crash with AWS CustomTabsManagerActivity.java (class is part of AWS library) class stating that activity not found.
Mentioning below the exact error message -

```
Caused by android.content.ActivityNotFoundException
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://auth.xyz.com/... pkg=com.android.chrome (has extras) }
```